# Test if generic type is of particular Enum type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, enums

I have researched the questions on here, and also tried my own tests, but can't seem to perform a certain function if the type of my generic type is a particular enum type.

I am currently trying:

`if (typeof(T) is typeof(Enums.Status)) { .. }`

However, that results in a `Type expected` error. So now I feel quite silly, because isn't my Enum a type?

I also tried `if (typeof(T) is Enums.Status) { .. }` but alas; also no avail.

Now I know `T` is definitely type of `Enums.Status` as you can see by this quickwatch print out: `typeof(T) = {Name = "Status" FullName = "Data.Common.Utility.Enums+Status"}`

This is probably easy, could anybody let me know how I would test this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `typeof(T) == typeof(Enums.Status)`? Or maybe `default(T) is Enums.Status`? (Not 100% sure if the latter works, though.)

Comment: That's the very first thing I said I tried? Haven't tried default(T) is..

Comment: Omg, lol. Equals signs instead of `is` worked a treat. Why would that be? You would normally test with the `is` operator wouldn't you? Submit this as a question and I will accept for you.

Comment: `is` in C# doesn't do the same thing as in most other language -- it's like `instanceof` in Java. I'll post it as an answer, sure.

Comment: So it was probably testing if the type of `typeof(T)` is `Enums.Status`. Probably one parent too much?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- though I wouldn't call it "parent" since that's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
typeof(T) == typeof(Enums.Status)
```

I think

```
default(T) is Enums.Status
```

might be faster but I don't know if it works or not; give it a try.